# Increment non-static variable via static function

Tags: c++, oop, static, increment

I am making an ecosystem in C++ where **every** `ANIMAL` on my `playing_field` will `grow_older()` at the end of the year.

```
class ANIMAL
{
private:
    int age;

public:   

    ANIMAL()
    {
     age=0;
    }

    static void grow_older(){ age++; }
};
```

I know that [static methods can only use static data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/211137/why-can-static-methods-only-use-static-data), but is there any elegant way to have something similar to an `ANIMAL.grow_older();`? I could iterate through my `playing_field` and call `grow_older();` on each animal, but I was hoping there is some concept out there that I'm not aware of that avoids iterating through every instance of `ANIMAL` explicitly.

Comment: You should include C++ as a tag when asking questions here about C++.

Comment: If every animal needs its own `age` instance, you could instead store a fixed data member `time_of_birth` and just increment a static `current_time`... then compute the difference only when needed. When an `ANIMAL` is "born" (constructed?) you would assign `time_of_birth = current_time;`

Comment: But... This request doesn't make much sense to me. An animal isn't a collection of animals.

Comment: playing_field is a 2D array of animals

Comment: @mah could you please post your solution as an answer below? I am not understanding

Comment: I think what @mah said  is to calculate age dynamically by time_of_birth and current_time, instead of save age as  member variable.

Comment: But to compute this number in a static function requires me to look at non-static variable time_of_birth. I seem to be missing something.

Comment: @user3487243 computation would be an object method, not a static one. See my example as an answer below - perhaps it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no elegant way to increate the value of data members from many objects at once, so your options seem to be to either have a single static `age` (which I assume is not valid for your use case), to increase the `age` of all objects one at a time (by iterating through whatever container they're in to find each), or adopting a different solution completely.

One possible alternative solution is to not store `age` as a data member at all, but rather store a `time_of_birth` as a data member, and also keep track of a `current_time` as a static data member. Your class would then look something like:

```
class ANIMAL
{
private:
    int time_of_birth;
    static int current_time;

public:   

    ANIMAL()
    {
     time_of_birth=current_time;
    }

    static void grow_older(){ current_time++; }

    int age() { return current_time - time_of_birth; }
};
int ANIMAL::current_time = 0; /* defined in a source, not header file */
```

If each time you must increase the age you also need to examine the age (for example, to see if the animal must now be dead), there probably is no savings since you need to iterate through your menagerie anyway. On the other hand, if you do not need to examine the age as (or more) often than you need to increase it, this approach should perform better due to resulting in less work.

Comment: This cleared everything up. Although what I was asking for seems hack-ish, what you are doing makes sense. Thank you!